# Qiskit ground state solver error

Tags: qiskit

I followed the ground state Eigensolver tutorial in the qiskit document, I got the following error. Is there a solution? My version of qiskit is 0.44.2 and here is the link to that tutorial.

https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/nature/tutorials/03_ground_state_solvers.html

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Please do not post screenshots of codes and errors, rather use proper environment. This allows search machines to find your question easily. Moreover, could you please post your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems likely you just copied the tutorial notebook to run it locally. There is an `aux_files` folder under the tutorials folder that is also needed for that one and where that files exists as per the error. https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-nature/tree/main/docs/tutorials/aux_files

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!!